# On D&D Beyond, as a DM, how can I make custom weapons available to all of my players in a specific Campaign?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, homebrew, tools, dnd-beyond

From what I've found online, it looks like it [may not be possible](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/general-discussion/41932-adding-non-magical-custom-weapons) to [add homebrew nonmagical weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/d-d-beyond-feedback/89311-is-it-possible-to-add-homebrew-weapons). I could not, however, find information that was more recent that 2020, nor do I know the homebrew system well enough to imagine whatever workarounds folks may have come up with (e.g., making a magic item that isn't magical).

I am running a Campaign in D&D Beyond and I would like to make several homebrew weapons that any player in the campaign can add to their character sheet and use. At least some of my players aren't going to spend the time to add these weapons themselves if they require customization, but they **will** add them to their character sheets if they can follow the normal path for adding an item.

Is there a method, short of editing their character sheets myself, where I can make custom weapons available within a Campaign?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Use the “Create Homebrew Item” tool.

Under the homebrew section of DND Beyond, there will be an option to create magic items. [This page](https://www.dndbeyond.com/homebrew/creations/create-magic-item) is where you will start. While this is described as creating *magic* items, *this is the only way to create custom items on DND Beyond*, and creating a mundane weapon is as simple as writing “this weapon is nonmagical” in its description.

The easiest way to do this is probably to create a copy of an existing +1 weapon that uses the same damage dice as your weapon:

[image]

And then delete the +1 modifier off of it:

[image]

Once created, every player in your campaign (and every player in every campaign you are in) will be able to find the item by searching for it in the manage inventory section of the character sheet. The item list in the manage inventory section makes it pretty difficult to distinguish between official and homebrew content, so I generally like to put "(Homebrew)" in the item's name so that other players who see it aren't confused about its source.

For example, I've created a "Baseball Bat with Nails", and searching "baseball" in the manage inventory box yields:

[image]

Using a longsword +1 as a base, I removed the +1 bonus and added a "Replace Damage Type" modifier to change the slashing damage to piercing damage:

[image]

---

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that all homebrew in the collection of anyone in a campaign group on D&D Beyond will be automatically shared with everyone else in that campaign. So if you create homebrew and don't want your players to be able to see it yet, I believe you can remove it from your own collection; you'll still be able to see it in your created homebrew, but it won't automatically be shared to others.

Comment: That said, I should also mention that while you can use *private* homebrew however you want, you shouldn't try to *publish* homebrew content *publicly* if it violates the homebrew publishing rules on DDB – e.g. if you create a homebrew magic item that's actually nonmagical, or if you create a homebrew feat that's actually meant to replicate something that's not meant to be a feat (e.g. to grant certain benefits of a magic item). You don't need to publish homebrew for it to be accessible to your campaign group, as noted above.

Comment: @V2Blast I'm not familiar with how publishing works in D&D Beyond. Are there steps I should take or avoid to make sure I don't do this. This will be my first time creating homebrew content of any kind.

Comment: @mkdir: Homebrew won't be published publicly unless you're trying to do so. [Here's a help page explaining how you would publish your homebrew publicly](https://dndbeyond-support.wizards.com/hc/en-us/articles/7747241293844-Introduction-Tutorial-), if that were what you were trying to do. It would require clicking "Publish" at the top of the page when viewing your homebrew; a confirmation dialog then appears with a link to the [Public Homebrew Content Rules & Guidelines](https://www.dndbeyond.com/homebrew-rules-guidelines) – and your homebrew is only published if you click "Submit" there.

Comment: (...Let me tell you, though: a lot of people do exactly that, and then message the mods saying they didn't mean to publish their homebrew/didn't see the rules for public homebrew – despite there being a confirmation dialog and everything.)

Comment: As someone who does support for a tech company, I 100% believe you could make a button that says "only click this if you want X", surround it with old style marquee and blink tags, and you'd still have about 25% of users then message you saying "but I didn't want X". Thanks for the info!